# how to develop a customized toolbar for my Saas product?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, browser

I have a SAAS recruitment Product which has an unique userid and password to login for our clients.

I want to have our customized tool bar to be fixed in the browser of the client and they need to get updates on the same.

Something like facebook addons.

The above is the basic Idea what I want to implement.
I need suggestions on how to go about it.

PS: it should be compatible with all the browsers.

Any where where java awt is used is also welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Compatible with all the browsers" implies that you don't want a browser plugin (why tagged "firefox-addon"?). Unless you're planning to implement an individual toolbar addon for each major browser.

Why don't you simple add the toolbar to your web application? Like the chat-bar on facebook that's always at the bottom of the facebook page. Look into the CSS "position: fixed" method, http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a browser toolbar I think is a bad idea, in my experience nobody likes to install toolbars in their system. But, if you're talking about in-page toolbar a little of CSS + Javascript (and jQuery) + HTML (obviously) will do, it would be very easy to implement but, of course, getting it to be of good quality is a little harder.

You can search for:

- CSS Fixed position
- jQuery AJAX
- Ticker

Also, be sure to understand the CSS basics first (Box model, basic hacks, etc) , it's essential.

Cheers.